# How to find a particular string in an array without knowing fully string name

Tags: arrays

I have an array in the object that contain class names of an HTML element.now i want a particular class name from an array and want to store in some variable but i don't know full class name.so how can i achieved this.

```
var arr = ["tile", "tile-2", "tile-new", "tile-position-1-4", value: "tile tile-2 tile-new tile-position-1-4"];
```

So here i need tile-position-1-4 to be get fetch from array and store in some variable and i only know about class name starts with tile-position.

my object structure is like this.

```
var obj={
     tile-position:""
      }
```

the tile-position-1-4 keeps getting updated so i dont know last numbers but what i know is that it starts with tile-position-[1-4]-[1-4].

Comment: you have both your `array` and `object` structures wrong. Can you please check those. That array is not the array of objects you are talking about

Comment: your object will contain only 1 key always?

Comment: my array contains a set of string and i want a particular string from array and gets store in object obj.tile-position but thing is i don't know string what i know is that it always start with tile-position.

Comment: yes @sravan my object contain only one key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the required solution:

Steps:

1. First the `array` and the `object` are taken.
2. Next we fetch the `key` of the `object`.
3. Next we search the `substring` of the `key` from the `array`
4. Next, we add that `string` from `array` into the `value` of that
   `object`

```js
var foundString = "";
var arr = ["tile", "tile-2", "tile-new", "tile-position-1-4"];
var obj = {   'tile-position':""  }
var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
for(i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++){
  if(arr[i].indexOf(key) > -1){
    obj[key] = arr[i]
  }
}
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
var string_obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = string_obj;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="demo">Hello!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/hOivWBzsRc6vGHZYa11d?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Do create object like:

```
var obj = {
    "tile: : "tile",
    "tile-2" : "tile-2",
    "tile-new" : "tile-new", 
    "tile-position-1-4" : "tile-position-1-4"
}
```

I think you do not have problem with it. Then you're able to get it as `var res = obj["tile-position-1-4"]`.

***P.S.*** Sorry, probably I do not understand correctly structure of your boject.